# Is there a way to create a jar from a directory with Python?

Tags: python

I want to generate a jar in a Python script with assets that are dynamically generated and `.class` files.

Could I just create a `.zip` file and rename the file extension?

Comment: what is your purpose of creating jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just create a ZIP file and rename the extension. It's that easy.

Do keep in mind that you might want to add (beside your class files) some metadata related files of a JAR (Java Archive), such as:

```
META-INF/
    MANIFEST.MF
```